# Mongoidalize throws NameError, uninitialized constant Mongoid::Relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, relationship

project isn't complicated, but finding my way around mongoid relationships has been. It would be nice to find some in depth explanation.

I couldn't make my code work however I set them up so I managed to find Mongoid_Alize: https://github.com/dzello/mongoid_alize

Yet when I do it with alize or alize_to/_from, console gives me back an error on Mongoid::Relations in Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/mongoid_alize-b9175f4e3165/lib/mongoid/alize/macros.rb:79:in `_alize_relation_types'"

I have also included eager loading with identity_map_enabled: true in mongoid.yml

So here's the code:

Currency.rb

```
class Currency
include Mongoid::Document
include Mongoid::Alize

field :name, type: String
field :state, type: String
field :code, type: Integer
field :unit, type: Integer

has_many :currency_value
has_many :value, :class_name => 'Value', :inverse_of => :currency
alize_to :value
end
```

Value.rb

```
class Value

include Mongoid::Document
include Mongoid::Alize

field :date, type: DateTime
field :buying, type: String
field :middle, type: String
field :selling, type: String


belongs_to :value_currency, :class => 'Currency', :inverse_of => :currency_value
belongs_to :currency, :class_name => 'Currency', :inverse_of => :value
alize_from :currency
end
```

ApiService.rb

```
class ApiService
  # Has some api data coming from external function getApiData

def update()

 @arrayOfHashes= getApiData() #array of hashes

 @arrayOfHashes.each do |hash|
   @currency = Currency.new({
    name: hash["Name"],
    state: hash["State"],
    code: hash["Currency code"],
    unit: hash["Unit"]
  })
  @currency.create_value(
    date => hash["Date of value"],
    buying => hash["Value when buying"],
    middle => hash["Middle value"],
    selling => hash["Value when selling"])
  @currency.save
end

return @currency
end
end
```

Expected result: save all 13 iterations in MongoDB with their relations.

It would be much obliged to hear some explanation here cause I'm uninspired and stuck in place. I have some background in programming and i have a feeling that it shouldn't be that complicated.

I can save either Currency model or Value but not both with their relations. Other idea is to do it manually by adding a custom foreign_id and making a method in the model which will populate hash. But that could lead to future performance issues.

Any help is appreciated, thank you :)